# Let $q :X \to Y$ be a quotient map, $f: X \to Z$ a continuous map and $h:Y \to Z$ a map such that $f = h \circ q$. Is $h$ is continuous also?

Tags: general-topology

> Let $q :X \to Y$ be a quotient map, $f: X \to Z$ a continuous map and $h:Y \to Z$ a map such that $f = h \circ q$. Can we conclude from this information that $h$ must be continuous also?

I don't think we can make this conclusion. Even though $f$ is continuous, then also $h \circ q$ is continuous, but I think we can have a composition of non-continuous and continuous maps that are continuous. So is there some property of the quotient map that would make this result true?

Answer (score 1):

Since $q$ is a quotient map, for $U\subseteq Z$ open we have $f^{-1}(U)\subseteq X$ open and hence $q(f^{-1}(U))\subseteq Y$ open. On the other hand we have $h^{-1}(U)=q(f^{-1}(U))$ since $f^{-1}(U)=q^{-1}(h^{-1}(U))$, so yes, $h$ is continuous.